# How to deselect all MenuStripItems?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make sort of a selector/last detector in my menustrip. Essentially I have a bunch of "sub items" under one menu strip item. And I want to go through all of them, uncheck them, and then check only the one that was clicked.

[image]

Essentially I want to uncheck all of the stuff that starts with de_ (and that last one, so all of them)

Edit: Got it to work, here is the code I ended up using

```
private void ItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in mapsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
  {
    item.Checked = false;
  }
  ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Checked = true;
}
```

But I'm not sure what to replace that ? with in order to look into the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the parent menu's DropDownItems collection:

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in mapStripMenuItem.DropDownItems ) {
  item.Checked = false;
}
```

From you image, it should be named Map-something, I'm guessing.

Comment: Yup! I didn't know DropDownItems existed. Thanks, edited final code into first post

Comment: To reduce logic based on menu item text you could use the ToolStripItem's Tag property to categorize the menu items.

Comment: I wasn't actually doing that - I'm targeting all of the items under maps, so that de part was irrelevant. But thanks for the Tag tip - I've sometimes used the Name itself to save some information into controls